# 'UIKit/UIUserActivity.h' file not found, Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native

I created a new `react native 0.60.5` project called `iostest` with react native init, opened 'iostest.xcworkspace', clicked run and got - Build Failed:
/Users/ronsivan/Desktop/iostest/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/RCTLinkingManager.h:10:9: 'UIKit/UIUserActivity.h' file not found

I've tried deleting `node_modules` and `npm install`, reinstalling cocoapods didn't work.

I'm running hackintosh with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and Xcode 9.4.
React Native documentation says that developing requires Xcode 9.4 or newer but this doesn't seem to be reliable.

Comment: facing same issue.  If you find any solution comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the same versions. As far as I know UIKit is coming with xcode. So I decided to upgrade the xcode to a version which is compatible with **macOS High Sierra 10.13.6** . You can check the xcode versions from https://xcodereleases.com/ . I upgraded the version to **10.0** and the problem was over. Hope it would be helpful for you as well.